# How to do this replacement without a for loop?

Tags: replacement

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to get past my desire to use `For` loops for everything; can somebody tell me a simple way to make this replacement? I want my input to be

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}
```

and my output to be

```
{p[1,2]p[3,4],p[1,4]p[2,3]}
```

Comment: `Times @@@ Apply[p, list, {2}]`?

Comment: This is great and simple, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

J.M.'s answer in comments is what I would have done too.

```
Times @@@ Apply[p, list, {2}]
```

But for completeness, you might be interested in this rule-based method of getting the `p` elements:

```
Times @@@ (a /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> p[x, y])
```

The test for `_AtomQ` is important (you could also use `_?NumericQ` or simple pattern `_Integer, depending on the scope of your actual problem). Otherwise the rule will just match the top level of your nested list and not replace anything else.

This being Mathematica, there are many ways to get the same result, but J.M.'s is the most succinct that I can think of.

Comment: In effect, the snippet I gave applies twice; first, at level 2 to replace the head `List` with `p` (`{{p[1,2], p[3,4]}, {p[1,4], p[2,3]}}`), and then at level one to replace `List` with `Times`.

Answer (score 0):

```
☺ @ ☺☺_ := 1 ## & @@ ☺☺ @@@ # & /@ # &;

☺[p] @ {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}
```

> {p[1, 2] p[3, 4], p[1, 4] p[2, 3]}